# android- How do I launch an Activity from a item in Reyclerview?

Tags: android-fragments, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am trying to launch an activity from a recyclerview's item using OnClick method. I made an interface and used getAdapterPostion in the adapter. But the Activity is not launching. Here's my code:

Interface that I created in my Adapter:

```
 public interface Clicklistener{
    public void itemClicked(View view,int position);
}
```

}

Setter method for ClickListener:

```
public void setclickListener(Clicklistener clickListener){

this.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

View Holder Method where I set the OnClickListener:

```
public   class ViewHolderListMovies extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView movieThumbnail;
    private TextView movieTitle;
    private TextView movieYear;





public ViewHolderListMovies(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            movieThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_poster);
            movieTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_name);
            movieYear = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_year);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(clickListener!=null){
                clickListener.itemClicked(v,getAdapterPosition());

            }

        }
```

The I Initialised the the interface in the fragment:

```
listMoviesAdapter.setclickListener(this);
```

At last I started an intent in in the fragment to call the needed Activity:

```
 @Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),MovieDetailsActivity.class));

}
```

Any Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is your itemClicked called at all?

Comment: I mean is it triggered? Try to write a short Toast or Log message to see if the code is executed in the itemClicked in your Fragment. And do you get any error in your logcat when you click on the item to open the activity.

Comment: I tried what you said and the itemClicked is not getting triggered.

Comment: Can you post the fragment code where you initialize the adapter and set the click listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise the setoncliklistener in method onBindViewHolder. Example, may be help

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mDataSet;
private List<String> mIdevent;


public HistoryAdapter(Context context, List<String> dataSet, List<String> idevent, List<String> askPrice, 
        List<String> bidPrice, List<String> Profit) {

    mContext = context;
    mDataSet = dataSet;
    mIdevent = idevent;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {      

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_list_history, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.add2new).into(holder.image);
    holder.text.setText(mDataSet.get(position));


    holder.setClickListener(new HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v, int pos, boolean isLongClick) {
            if (isLongClick) {

                // View v at position pos is long-clicked.
                String poslx = pos + "";
                String menax = mDataSet.get(pos);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "longclick pos. " + poslx + " pair " + menax, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                // View v at position pos is clicked.
                //String possx = pos + "";
                String poslx = pos + "";
                String event2 = mDataSet.get(pos); 
                String id2 = mIdevent.get(pos);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "shortclick pos. " + poslx + " pair " + event2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //toggleSelection(pos);

                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, HistoryCandlesActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("eventx", event2);
                extras.putString("idx", id2);
                extras.putInt("whatspage", 0);
                i.putExtras(extras);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);


            }
        }
    });

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}

public void remove(int position) {
    mDataSet.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void add(String text, int position) {
    mDataSet.add(position, text);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    public ImageView image;
    public TextView text;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        // We set listeners to the whole item view, but we could also
        // specify listeners for the title or the icon.
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    }


    /* Interface for handling clicks - both normal and long ones. */
    public interface ClickListener {

        /**
         * Called when the view is clicked.
         *
         * @param v view that is clicked
         * @param position of the clicked item
         * @param isLongClick true if long click, false otherwise
         */
        public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick);

    }

    /* Setter for listener. */
    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // If not long clicked, pass last variable as false.
        clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        // If long clicked, passed last variable as true.
        clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), true);
        return true;
    }


  }
}
```